# android delete item from database but not form list view

Tags: android

I have an custom list view with data from my database.
In my list adapter I set an `onlongclicklistener` to delete an item in my database:

```
row.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle(context.getResources().getString("TITEL"));

            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "NO",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "YES",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            String delete = "DELETE FROM "+DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE+" " +
                                    "WHERE "+DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID+" = "+databaseListItems.getID();

                            sqlHandler = new DatabaseHandler(context);
                            sqlHandler.executeQuery(delete);

                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

            alertDialog.show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Item will be deleted in database, but not in list view. If I reload my list view, the item will disappear
How can I reload my list view after deleting?

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I'm not clear what you want. Do you want delete items fromdatabase and ListView or just want to detele in db but not in ListView?

Comment: By simply calling the Adapter's `notifyDatasetChanged()` after the Dialog returned.

Comment: Deleting from database does not mean re-rendering view you create, thus you should make it manually as above answers says.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein notifyDataSetChanged is not some magical function that will reload data itself, its only inform the Adapter that underlaing data is changed ... but if you didn't chane it by yourself it will not help

Comment: Remove the item from your adapter dataSet then call notifyDatasetChanged(), or just reload the whole dataSet from your database.

Comment: notificationList.remove(selectedItem); notifyItemRemoved(selectedItem); notifyItemChanged(selectedItem);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After executing the Database query , delete the item from the arraylist which you are using to populate the listview by using this

```
myList.delete(position);
```

and call

```
notifyDatasetChanged();
```

for getting the item position , you can set setOnItemLongClickListener on listview.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow two steps:

1) When you confirm the delete, you have to remove the item from the object that you use in the adapter to fill the list

2) Then, you have to call `notifyDatasetChanged()`

If you don't delete the item from the adapter, it will be loaded again in the list calling `notifyDatasetChanged()`